# Need XORd briefly explained for Cryptopals Crypto Challenge 3 set 1

Tags: python-3.x, math, cryptography

i just have a quick question on this bit of code i have here on the Cryptopals Challenges, using Python3, For XORing a string with one single character.The program takes in a hex string string, decodes it, XORs it with a single character, does this for every possible character, then finds the "most english" line of XORd data.  heres my code snippet (which i admittdly used from a solutions page ) :

```
def singlechar_xor(input_bytes, key_value):
    """XORs every byte of the input with the given key_value and returns the result."""
    output = b''
    for char in input_bytes:
        output += bytes([char ^ key_value])
    return output
```

i know what is happening and i understand what is supposed to happen, im just not sure how bytes behave and what types are and arent supposed to be XORd. Why do i need the brackets around char^key_value? If i remove the brackets my output becomes a bunch of 0's. What is the result of the XOR or the character and the key_value? If someone could kindly explain so i could have a better understanding going forward in these challenges id GREATLY appreciate it <3